# Will LattePanda IPS display work with raspberry pi zero?

Tags: display

I have LattePanda but its connector to which we connect flex cable is broken, so i am thinking to buy a pi zero and use it instead to display graphs. However i am not sure if it will work.

Comment: Hi, Ciasto piekarz, Ah, let me see.  So you have a LattePanda running full Win10.  Now you want to throw it away, but keep the display/monitor and use RpiZ instead of LattePanda to display graphs.  Now the critical thing is what monitor you have been using.  If it is a ordinary HDMI thing, say 22" XYZ brand, then it is 90% likely to use the monitor for other computers, such as Win7/10 PC, linux PC such as Rpi. But if you Panda HDMI monitor is Windows only, and you don't have linux drivers for it, then you have little luck.

Comment: What  I never said i will throw away LattePanda, I just want to use the display with pi zero and since I mentioned flex , that obviously means i am not talking about hdmi connection.

Comment: My apologies.  My IQ is only 97, so what you think "obvious" is not so for me. Now let me wild guess again.  You have a Win10 Panda working perfectly, except the flexible cable connecting Panda to a small 2.8" LCD mon is broken.  I guess Panda has another big HDMI monitor.  It is now obvious to me in that Panda has two mons, one big 28", and another small 2.8". What is still not obvious to me is: (1)  Which end of the flexible cable is broken, Panda side or Mon side? (2) Why not buying a new flex cable instead of a RpiZ?

Comment: Usually 2.8"  LCD has 16 pins connected to a signal routing board with a LCD display controller, which in turn has a 4 wire SPI cable connected to the Panda.  Now if the SPI cable is not broken, you can connect it to RpiZ, without problem, because RpiZ talks SPI.  Another problem is that Panda should have a SPI driver for the 2.8" mon, but if there is not any corresponding driver for raspbian, you might have a problem.

Comment: Sorry, You dont sound like part of the league where you are posting. Thanks anyway

Comment: sorry for my low iq.

Comment: @tlfong01, the post seems to say that the connector on the LattePanda board is broken ... the LCD flex cable is not damaged

Comment: @jsotola, Ah, many thanks for pointing out my careless English translation mistake. I looked back the phrase I wrongly read: "... its connector to which we connect flex cable is broken, ...". I am weak in reading long sentences, so often misunderstand them.  I need to translate the long phrase into something like this: "... My computer's connector to the second monitor is broken, ...". The confusion arises because I didn't know "flex" was "flexible" for short, and it should be the usual mult-pin, delicate, easy to break, flat ribbon cable like those used by the Rpi camera.  / to continue, ...

Comment: Actually I have a couple of HDMI cables. one is a flexible flat ribbon cable, another is also flexible, and thin (thinner than an ordinary USB) cable.  I do have other HDMI monitor cables, very stiff, very thick (almost 1cm in diameter), very long, heavily double shielded, for use in heavy duty, mission critical,  situations/functions, like in a conference room, ...